# it gives me this error:-executenonquery connection property has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls; using System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Configuration; using System.Data;  public partial class working : System.Web.UI.Page {      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     {      }     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     {         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=working;Integrated Security=True");         con.Open();         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;         cmd.CommandText="insert into sample(name,mobile_number,email_id,gender) values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"','"+TextBox4.Text+"')";         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         con.Close();         Response.Write("submitted");     } }

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide the connection string like this
"""Data Source=DEVELOPER;Initial Catalog=working;Integrated Security=True""""

"""
Data Source=DESKTOP-SIJVIOU\SQLSERVERPOONIA;Initial Catalog=YourDBName;Integrated Security=True" providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"""